# C++ firebase application windows application, CMake needed or VS project only possible?

Tags: c++, windows, firebase, visual-studio

As stated here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android#ndk-build

One need CMake. Is this really needed or is it enough to add libs and headers to my VS2019 project?

Comment: Why would anyone voluntarily offer to suffer? MSBuild is designed for .NET and its build model. That's *substantially* different from C's and C++'. MSBuild barely works for stock native projects. Anything beyond that and you'll be switching build systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ SDK was made with CMake in mind and is listed as a [requirement](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk#prerequisites), this is for compiling and ensuring the SDK is cross-platform. You may be able to get away without it if you manually add the libraries and correct headers, but there is no guarantee all the services would work as intended.

If this is not an option for you, it might be more efficient to simply make a wrapper for the Rest API and making custom requests.
You will have to take notes on the life cycle of certain events and manage your secret keys, refresh tokens, etc.